# How can I allow specific Magento Store Dashboard

Tags: magento, store, dashboard

Intro:
We have a multi-store environment in which each store has a unique "manager" (identified internally as a type of client / different from the customers who actually purchase).

We need to:
Allow the specific manager to see how many visits are made to the store and the orders placed under his/her store. We can, of course, see orders from any and all stores but we would like each "manager" to have the possibility without being able to see any other store.

We don't give the managers access to the Magento backend so the data has to be accessed elsewhere (from within the "My Account" section in the store or from a separate web app, for example).

We have looked within Magento and, short of developing Database access from scratch, haven't found anything that allows this functionality.

Any thoughts (or Magento extensions) to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most clean and easy way to do this, is to use an observer for the event `sales_order_place_after` that tracks placed orders, checks the store where the order is placed, and sends orders to the platform of the relevant manager.

Your module config.xml should look like:

```
<config>
    <!-- ... -->
    <global>
        <!-- ... -->
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <namespace_module>
                        <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
                        <method>yourMethod</method>
                    </namespace_module>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
        <!-- ... -->
    </global>
    <!-- ... -->
</config>
```

Create namespace/module/Model/Observer.php. This file should look like:

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function yourMethod($observer)
    {
         $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()
         $storeId = $order->getStoreId();

         // Your code logic to send order
    }
}
```

Comment: Gerard, thank you very much. We will look into your proposal and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Magento community does not have permission system on store basis this is something thats in enterprise version.

There are some extensions available that will handle to some extent.

As far as I can recall there is some multi vendor module that has some of these features.

Answer (score 0):

Use Multivendor Magento EXtension. By using this extension you can see orders from any and all the stores. Moreover vendors can easily share their product information from single store & add or update the product details. Admin have all rights to accept or reject the vendor request any time, this is the main function of this extension.